# Threefold-symmetry in non-landing spacecraft?

Tags: design

Many spacecraft have [twofold symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandra_X-ray_Observatory), some have [fourfold symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariner_5).

Have any spacecraft had *threefold* symmetry?

I'm specifically looking at ones that don't land on the surface of a planet/moon/whatever.

Comment: Iridium satellites too, I'd suggest. (Three large antenna panels.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [COBE](http://lambda.gsfc.nasa.gov/product/cobe/) the Cosmic Background Explorer.

[image]

And the [Inflatable Antenna Experiment](http://www.lgarde.com/assets/content/files/publications/96-1367.pdf) launched on STS-77

[image]

At least until it got all twisted up.